# Lamp Forbidden

Tags: веб-сервер, lamp, сервер, ubuntu

Всем привет)

Поставил на ubuntu LAMP, Webmin. Через webmin создал виртуальный хост. ip - 192.168.0.104. Папку поставил /home/inferusvv/www.

Однако когда заходишь по адресу 192.168.0.104 выдает forbidden, а не открывает индексовый файл..

Я, конечно, не только через webmin, но и вручную пробовал - никак..

localhost открывается без проблем (`/var/www/`).

Помогите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

1) Сударь а Апач у Вас настроен под Ваш сайт?
2) А по ip адресу Вы пытаетесь зайти с того же компьютера?

Comment: Все уже ок. Надо было apache2.conf подправить и добавить <directories /home/inferusvv/www>...

Comment: как я и предполагал - п.1